# Unable to kubectl connect my kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

With a Kubernetes cluster up and running and the ability to go to the master over ssh with ssh-keys and run kubectl commands there; I want to run kubectl commands on my local machine. So I try to setup the configuration, following the [kubectl config](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-cluster/):

```
kubectl config set-cluster mykube --server=https://<master-ip>:6443
kubectl config set-context mykube --cluster=mykube --user=mykube-adm
kubectl config set-credentials mykube-adm --client-key=path/to/private/keyfile
```

Activate the context:

```
kubectl config use-context mykube
```

When I run a kubectl command:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

It returns:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

**The output of `kubectl config view`**

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://<master-ip>:6443
  name: mykubecontexts:
- context:
    cluster: mykube
    user: mykube-adm
  name: mykube
current-context: mykube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: mykube-adm
  user:
    client-key: path/to/private/keyfile
```

Comment: In the second block, did you mean `kubectl config use-context mykube`?

Comment: Please post the output of `kubectl config view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, above `kubectl` config file is incorrect. It seems an error appeared due to manual formatting or something else.

New line is missing in this part (`name: mykubecontexts:`):

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://<master-ip>:6443
  name: mykubecontexts:
- context:
    cluster: mykube
    user: mykube-adm
  name: mykube
```

Correct one is:

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://<master-ip>:6443
  name: mykube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: mykube
    user: mykube-adm
  name: mykube
```

That's why cluster's name is `mykubecontexts:`:

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://<master-ip>:6443
  name: mykubecontexts:
```

and that's why there is no context in it, because `contexts:` is not defined.

`kubectl` cannot find context `mykube` and switches to default one where `server=localhost:8080` is by default.

`kubectl` config is located in `${HOME}/.kube/config` file by default if `--kubeconfig` flag or `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable are not set.

Please correct it to the following one:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://<master-ip>:6443
  name: mykube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: mykube
    user: mykube-adm
  name: mykube
current-context: mykube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: mykube-adm
  user:
    client-key: path/to/private/keyfile
```